# Creating Anaconda 4.5 environment with Python 3.4 in offline mode?

Tags: python, anaconda, version

I have installed Anaconda 4.5 on an offline machine. This version of Anaconda comes with Python 3.6 by default. I now wish to create a new environment with Python 3.4.

I have searched extensively and cannot find a means by which I can create this environment in offline mode. If this machine was on the internet I could simply do

```
conda create -n py34 python=3.4
```

and it would automagically download the necessary Python 3.4 packages and install them.

---

I initially thought I might find a/the Python 3.4 .bz2 package on Conda Forge and install it in my root environment, though, this package does not seem to exist? **Where can I find the conda Python 3.4 .bz2 package?** (I have the Python 3.4 tar.gz and .tgz packages from python.org, though, Anaconda doesn't seem to support the file type)

Even if I did have this package, I feel like I should not install it directly in my root environment? I think I need to provide the .bz2 file path to the `conda create` command directly? Though again, I can not seem to find any information about this online. **Provided the Python 3.4 .bz2 package, how can I create an environment using it in offline mode?**